# Is it possible to hide iOS system alert for NFC reading session

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

When you successfully finish an `NFC` reading session you'll see something like that:

[image: Successfully finished NFC session]

This will overlay the currently presented `ViewController` for about 3 seconds. The fun part is that this behaviour is inconsistent since this window will disappear immediately if the reading session finish very fast.

It means that I cannot be sure about how long will this overlay stay for sure which is bad for our app's UX design.

The question is simple: is there a way to force this overlay to disappear or at least to handle the event of when it disappears (not when the `NFC`  session if finished)?

Comment: Can you show some code?  What you are describing sounds like you aren't using the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 it's a part of a commercial product so I guess that I can't. I'm sure that completion is executed on the main thread since it's handled by `RxSwfit` `.observeOn(MainScheduler())`. Moreover, the behaviour is consistent as I mentioned: if the reading session is finished very fast (in < 0.5 sec) this system alert is dismissed immediately. Any time the session is longer - this alert is presented for about 3 seconds (always the same time, not different) before being dismissed.

Comment: What queue do you pass when you set up your `NFCNDefReaderSession`?  Try this and see if you get the same behaviour; https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't add a custom queue for `NFCNDefReaderSession` so it chooses some background queue (not main) under the hood but I observe the results on the main queue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found an interesting way to hide that window. 2 simple steps are required:

1) When initialising your reader session set the last parameter to false: `NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)`

2) In the body of `readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage])` your should call `session.invalidate()`.

That's it. It will work as if you tapped Cancel/Done - the system window will disappear immediately.

Comment: Actually you might want delay session invalidation for about 0.5 seconds, so user will have a chance to see checkmark screen

Comment: This doesn't work. At least not on iOS 12. The dialoge remains for around a second no matter what. Basically breaks any useful application of NFC.

Comment: Since you cannot control when this disappears, what is the best alternative?  See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207514/how-can-apps-display-the-result-of-an-nfc-read-until-the-user-chooses-to-dismiss