# iOS Dismiss instantly NFCTagReaderSession result view

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

I am working with the `iSO14443` tag now, and I am trying to dismiss the `NFCTagReaderSession` result view controller (check below image) after finishing communication with a tag since it takes too long to dismiss (Our app is frequently reading a tag).

[image]

I have tried to dismiss the presenting view and the root view controller, but I failed.

```
//Dismiss Presenting View Controller
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)

//Dismiss Root View Controller
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Also, I have found a similar question([Is it possible to hide iOS system alert for NFC reading session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464810/is-it-possible-to-hide-ios-system-alert-for-nfc-reading-session)), but it is for reading `NDEF` tag.

Is there a way to dismiss it or I cannot?

Comment: Share code with completion block.

Comment: Imho you can set again rootviewcontroller with desired view  controller, that is simple to do.

Comment: @user3344236 I am an Android developer, and I just started studying iOS,  so could you show the example code for me?

Comment: let rearViewController = storyboard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC") as? MyVC
        let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        window.rootViewController = rearViewController where storyboard1 is an existing one and MyVC also is a UIViewController in that storyboard.

Comment: Hey, any update for this issue ?

Comment: I have worked in many ways but I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: too bad, I also need a solution for this issue. Why is Apple forcing us to watch the screen block for several seconds after a NFC tag read ? I do not want this badly looking modal sheet blocking all of my UI after a tag-read. It should work as Android can do it - i.e. without modal-sheet...

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on this NFC but I found this [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcreadersessionprotocol) which says by invalidating the delegate the pop up will dismiss. [like invalidating timer]

```
 func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        var result = ""
        for payload in messages[0].records {
            result += String.init(data: payload.payload.advanced(by: 3), encoding: .utf8)!
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.messageLabel.text = result
            self.nfcSession?.invalidate()//try this line *
        }
    }
```

also I have referred [this](https://www.appcoda.com/corenfc-introduction/) for basic knowledge. hope this help you. happy codding.

Comment: Yeah, `invalidate()` will dismiss pop up, but the pop up will be dismissed after few seconds. What I want is dismiss immediately.

Comment: nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true) have you given true for invalidate after first read

Comment: Also, I am working with a normal tag which is `iSO14443`, not the NDEF tag, so I am not using `NFCNDEFReaderSession`, so I am using `NFCTagReaderSession`. But, thank you for helping!

Comment: exactly, I am also using `NFCTagReaderSession` - and the `invalidate()` method works but still keeps this badly-looking result modal-sheet up on hold during at least 3-4 seonds. Way too long. I wish there is an option to not show this modal-sheet at all. As Android can  do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code is like this:

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        
    guard let tag = tags.first else { return }
        
    if case let NFCTag.miFare(miFareTag) = tag {
        session.connect(to: tag, completionHandler: { error in 
            // do something
            session.invalidate()
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem is `session.connect()` will take long time, and I found that if you only need to read tag information, then `session.connect()` is no need, so I change my code into this:

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        
    guard let tag = tags.first else { return }
        
    if case let NFCTag.miFare(miFareTag) = tag {
        // do something
        session.invalidate()
    } 
}
```

and it will dismiss instantly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sheet to dismiss immediately you need to set `invalidateAfterFirstRead` to false when creating your `NFCNDEFReaderSession`.

```
let session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: .main, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
session.begin()
```

then in your `NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate`...

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
// do something interesting
    session.invalidate()
}
```

The 'tick' animation might get cut off... watch out for that.

Comment: OP is using NFCTagReaderSession, not NFCNDEFReaderSession. NFCTagReaderSession does not have the invalidateAfterFirstRead parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue seemed to because we were calling beginScanning() in two places. Both ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear. After removing the invocation from viewDidLoad, it is now dismissing instantly.