# How can apps display the result of an NFC read until the user chooses to dismiss?

Tags: ios, core-nfc

When reading NFC tags, iOS shows an action sheet at the bottom of the screen.  You can use this action sheet to display the process of the read, and also display the result.

**A general problem is that the app developer and the user has very little control over this action sheet** other than adjusting the `alertMessage`.  You can't control how long it is displayed or precisely control when it disappears.  I saw a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464810/is-it-possible-to-hide-ios-system-alert-for-nfc-reading-session) about hiding the NFC action sheet.  I know I can't do that.  So what is the alternative?

The code below tries to show the value read on this action sheet, but it disappears about 1 second after it is presented, which isn't long enough for the user to process the information displayed.  As an alternative, I show the same information in a pop-up dialog using a `UIAlertController` so the user can see the value read of as long as necessary before choosing to dismiss it.

**The specific problem is that the pop-up dialog shows up behind the action sheet for a full second and the whole process looks disjointed and awkward.**

Is there a smoother way to **display the result of a read that allows the user to continue to see the value read and control when it disappears**?  This is important for longer and more complex read values that take some time for the app user to read and intellectually process.

```
tag.readNDEF { message, error in
if let message = message {
  let textMessage = self.parsePayloads(payloads: message.records) ?? "(none)"
  session.alertMessage = "Field read: \(textMessage)"
  session.invalidate() 
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Field Read", message: textMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
   alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
   self.viewController?.present(alertView, animated: true)
  }}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set your session to invalidate automatically after the read?  Your would normally just update your view that is behind the NFC overlay and wait for it to disappear.  Using a modal alert view to show the value isn't what you would do in a real app.

Comment: The session.invalidate() is called programmatically when the read completes.  I could delay this call, but not indefinitely as the session will ultimately time out. 
I suppose I could transition to a full screen view that shows the read result which may be slightly less awkward looking, but it will still be behind the action sheet so it presents a similar issue.

Comment: What you are describing is the normal NFC reading experience on iOS. You can try with an NFC reader app from the App Store. Since you are invalidating the session you may as well just set the option to automatically invalidate it after the first read.